# Use Linux Find to search for directories that contain a file with properties

Tags: linux, bash, find, exec

I'm trying to find projects in an enormous directory. The projects are always several levels of depth in and have a config file which contains the project name. So basically...

Given a path  and string 
Return any directory that has a depth of 3 from the  and contains a file named "config"
that contains the

I learned that find combined with grep will work... but print out the grepped text and not the path of it's parent directory

`find <starting-dir> -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -type d -exec grep '<project-name>' {}/config \;`

Just prints out the project name :(

Perhaps there any way to switch back to find's default behaviour of printing out the found file path only if the grep is successful? Or is there another tool I should try to use to solve this?

Comment: `grep` has the `-l` flag/option, and many more options...

Comment: Gahh that's right. Updated with an answer

Comment: Does `grep -l "$project_name" "$startdir"/*/*/*/config` do what you want?

Comment: Hmm, I'm away from the machine right now but I assumed earlier that this would search every single subfile, of which there are very many. I'll try this out once I'm back to see if it hangs/takes forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `-print`, you need to add it explicitly after a succesful `-exec`.

For example, using grep's `-q`:

```
find <starting-dir> \
    -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 \
    -type d \
    -exec grep -q '<project-name>' {}/config \; \
    -print
```

---

As you discovered, grep already has `-l`.

You can reduce the number of `grep` processes:

```
find <starting-dir> \
    -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 4 \
    -type f -name config \
    -exec grep -l '<project-name>' {} +
```

Comment: That's interesting, from looking at the print documentation I didn't realize it could be used like that, . The last example is also helpful in understanding the difference between ending exec with '\' or '+'.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the -l flag to my output fixes the issue, for some reason I thought that would just print out "config" and not the whole path of that config file, but here we are.

`find <starting-dir> -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -type d -exec grep -l '<project-name>' {}/config \;`

This will print out the full path of the config file of the project you search for.